# Debounce in functional component

Tags: reactjs, next.js, debouncing

I have this functional component with debounce:

```
import React, {useCallback, Component, useState} from 'react';
import debounce from 'lodash.debounce';

function Tags() {

const [type, setType] = useState('');
...

    async function getSearchTag(keyword) {
       ....
       await axios.post(ajax_url, {keyword, tags : disabled_tags});

    };


    const onChangeDebounced = useCallback(debounce(getSearchTag(value), 500), [value]);
    

    const handleInputChange = (event) => {

        // Immediately update the state
        setValue(event.target.value);

        // Execute the debounced onChange method
        onChangeDebounced(event.target.value);
    }

    return (
        <div>
        ...
        <input type="text" name="tags" placeholder="Search for other tags..." onChange={(e) => 
        handleInputChange(e)}/>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Tags;
```

This is my first time setting up `debounce` in react, I am trying to convert a existing `react class component` to a `react functional component`.

I need to pass the `value` `state` to `getSearchTag()`, is the above implementation correct?

Comment: `setValue` does not immediately mutate `value` as state updates are async. So in `handleInputChange` you are passing the old value to `onChangeDebounced`. You should use `event.target.value` there too. Also you are calling `getSearchTag` indstead of passing it to `debounce`.

Comment: I see, do I need to change `onChangeDebounced(event.target.value);` inside `const handleInputChange` to `getSearchTag(event.target.value)` instead?

Answer (score 3):

You have added a dependency as value to `useCallback` which leads to a new **debounced function getting created everytime value state changes** which is the a cause of the problem.

Also you just need to `pass a function reference to debounce` and not invoke it

Your updated way of creating a debounce function will be as below

```
const onChangeDebounced = useCallback(debounce(getSearchTag, 500), []);
```